# Using a full archival node like Parity or Geth, how to query which is the last transaction which changed the value of a particular storage address

Tags: go-ethereum, query, openethereum, archive-node

I tried various third party services like Infura, and there support all told me that this was unsupported and that I would have to run my own Parity full archival node for this.

But even if I would have my full archival node (something now requiring [5TiB of ram worth 92,000$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database) in order to be build) which api along function I should use in order to get the transaction or block number used to set the lastest value of a storage address from a specific contract s?

Comment: Of course, I ve no idea how to do that having never be able to run my own node.

Comment: An archival node by itself will not be enough, the data is there but since it is not indexed you can't query easily. A blockchain indexer like github.com/poanetwork/blockscout might work for some contracts like ERC20 tokens, but it is not programmed to track arbitrary contracts.

Comment: @Ismael I m not talking about a full node but a full archival node. I also need to include the result of the past minute whatever the period of the day.

Comment: In my comment I did mention archival node, geth query functionality is very basic, to make complex queries like the one you want you have to create a program that access the database.

Comment: @Ismael Even for Parity too?

Comment: I haven't used parity a lot but probably it is quite similar to geth in that area, both are created to act as a blockchain client. A few years ago it was announed that ethereum blockchain will be available with bigquery, it seems it is available at kaggle.com/bigquery/ethereum-blockchain.

Comment: @Ismael but it s with daily extracts. You can t get the results for the past minute.

Comment: Another project that you may want to take a look at is quickblocks.io, but I haven't used it so I'm not sure if it will work for you. The only other option will be to modify an existing client to fit your needs.